# Iterating over vars **only** defined in inventory for a host

Tags: ansible

I would like to iterate over the vars defined in the **inventory file** of an ansible playbook. Indeed, in my inventory I define some vars to put in a .ini
file on the target host. I have something like this in my inventory file:

```
[myhost:vars]
VAR1=VALUE1
VAR2=VALUE2
```

I tried something like this:

```
- name: fill ini file with variables
  ini_file:
    path: "{{ myfile.ini }}"
    section: vars
    option: "{{ item.key }}"
    value: "{{ item.value }}"
    create: yes
    with_dict: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname] }}"
```

myfile.ini should look like this at the end:

```
[vars]
VAR1=VALUE1
VAR2=VALUE2
```

The problem is: I properly have 'VAR1' and 'VAR2', but also *all* the Ansible variables for the host. I would like to iterate only on those defined in
the inventory (`inventory_vars` ? Does not exist).

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Define a dictionary instead of unrelated keypairs.

Comment: @techraf could you please elaborate on this? An example would be great I am a beginner with Ansible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to determine were a certain fact/variable was set, or filter them by their origin.

Instead, you can define a dictionary (JSON) in your inventory:

```
[myhost]
localhost

[myhost:vars]
my_dict={"VAR1": "VALUE1", "VAR2": "VALUE2"}
```

and use it in the iterator:

```
with_dict: "{{ my_dict }}"
```

---

<sup>Mind that in your example `with_dict` is wrongly indented.</sup>